# Calling String from another method - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, using

I am trying to use this String called "username" from another method, but I can't seem to figure out what to do.

I have this bit of code right here, which assigns a text field's entry to a variable, but I can't seem to use this variable in another method

```
        //Configuring content pane
    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    formattedTextField.setBounds(129, 36, 120, 20);
    UsernameFrame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextField);
    UsernameFrame.setVisible(true);

    //Assigning text field entry to variable
    String username = formattedTextField.getText();
```

Now, I am trying to use this variable in the method pasted below, but I don't know what I am missing..

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(username.length() < 5){

            }
            //Execute when the button is pressed
            System.out.println("The button has been pressed");
        }
```

This is probably something really simple I am missing, thanks for your help guys.

(full code)

http://pastebin.com/RMszazd4

Comment: You probably want to declare `String username` in the class rather than in that particular method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `username` right after your class declaration like this:

```
public class App {
    private String username;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That sadly has not worked..  The variable is required to be there based off of the projects' setup.  I'll paste the full code in the topic to show what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

If these are two separate methods you will need to reassign the username variable again or you can create a global variable outside of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pass in the string variable "username"as a parameter to another method since it would not recognize the scope of your string in another method unless its declared global.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have a way of reading the JFormattedTextField. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you could declare formattedTextField as an instance variable, and then declare username inside the listener:

```
public class Frame {
JFrame UsernameFrame = new JFrame("Welcome");
private JFormattedTextField formattedTextField;
```

....

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String username = formattedTextField.getText();
            if (username.length() < 5) {

            }
            // Execute when the button is pressed
            System.out.println("The button has been pressed");
        }
    });
```

Now you have a reference to the text of the JFormattedTextField to do what you will with each time the button is pressed.